# When to use the first person plural form of imperative mood (disons, considérons, supposons, etc.)

Tags: registre-familier, mode-grammatical, registre, impératif, registre-soutenu

Sometimes, I am puzzled about whether  one can use the first plural form of the imperative mood in colloquial speech or in a more relaxed setting. Does the use of forms like

> Disons, considérons, supposons, faisons (l'hypothèse), imaginons,

and so on sound pompous in colloquial or/and relaxed speech?

I have a colleague (doctorat ès lettres) that uses turns like these very often during his courses. Some colleagues find that in the familiar setting of a course this usage of the 1st plural form of the imperative is not suitable; they consider it more compatible with a higher register. Are they right?

Last but not least, is there a one-to-one correspondence between the forms

> Let's + infinitive

and

> Impératif en -ons

?

Comment: I don't feel this usage per se pompous at all, it seems totally natural in a context of speech. It may be the whole way of speaking that is pompous, including the usage of 1 pers. pl. imperative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'impératif est un mode délicat à utiliser.
J'ai toujours hésité à l'employer en public tant **je** le trouve frôlant l'incorrection.

Je crois même ne l'avoir jamais utilisé qu'avec mes propres enfants.<sup>(1)</sup>

*Excusez-moi !* Et bhé c'est... si je veux!
*Ecoutez!* Tout pareil! Si je veux!

Le pire de tous est très certainement le verbe être!

*Soyez poli! Soyez gentil! Soyez prudent!*
Celui-là, je le considère carrément impoli depuis que... je suis capable de conjuguer *être* à la première personne, tout seul, comme un grand!

Le fait d'utiliser la première personne du pluriel donne à l'auditoire l'impression que l'auteur des propos s'inclut dans l'impératif. L'ordre n'est pas donné qu'aux autres, il concerne aussi le locuteur.

C'est parfois pertinent et justifié :

Nous nous emportons tous les deux et il serait bon que je m'arrête. Et puis vous aussi. :

*Arrêtons là! Restons-en là! Brisons là! (Voulez-vous ?)*

Loin de le trouver *pompeux*, **je** le trouve bien souvent un tantisoit : faux cul!

Tout le monde connaît le célèbre *Courage! Fuyons!* qui me permettra de... ne pas fuir tout seul et devoir assumer une certaine... lâcheté.

Dans le même ordre de chose... souhaitant partager l'irresponsabilité consistant à m'envoyer un dernier verre derrière la cravate... Je dirais (et même si je suis tout seul... avec moi-même...) **Soyons fous!**

Cette *impolitesse* n'a au demeurant jamais échappé à personne puisque... il existe un mode nommé très précisément : *L'impératif de politesse.*

Il s'agit de ce très... bon à tout faire : subjonctif!

Utilisé systématiquement bien sûr lorsqu'on demande un truc à Dieu... faut faire gaffe : *Dieu te **bénisse**! / Ainsi **soit**-il!*
Voire à d'autres machins surpuissants... : *La force soit avec toi!*

*La force **soit** avec toi!* qui se trouve au passage être la traduction convenue pour ***may*** the force be with you (et non pas *let* the force...)

Tout ceci pour justifier le fait que l'impératif... en cours... devant des élèves... 1pp ou 2pp... on évite! Après tout! Ni Dieu ni Maître! <sup>(2)</sup>

Et pourquoi s'en servir quand... une tournure permet de s'en sortir avec élégance, sans la moindre affectation et surtout, de façon totalement impersonnelle : **Le participe présent!**

Disons -> (En) disant
Considérons -> (En) considérant
Supposons -> (En) supposant
Faisons (l'hypothèse)-> En faisant l'hypothèse
Imaginons -> En imaginant.

On ne contraint personne... et surtout pas soi-même! Cool!

---

Je crois que l'impression de *pompeux* laissée par l'impératif 1pp est dû à l'emploi vieilli de la 1pp (de l'indicatif) en tant que 1ps dit *nous de majesté*.
Si **JE** dis : *Disons que blahblah* (alors qu'il n'y a que moi qui parle et que je ne demande à personne de dire quoi que ce soit), ce *disons* sera rapporté à ce *nous* de majesté que j'utiliserais alors effectivement très pompeusement. Ce *disons* perd sa réalité d'impératif pour paraître un *nous disons* indicatif mis pour un *je dis* de majesté.

---

<sup>1 : Du temps où... j'avais autorité sur eux... *fais pas çi / fais pas ça / moi aussi / on m'a dit ça!*</sup>

<sup>Ha! Si, aussi avec mes potes quand ils allaient faire une grosse bêtise... *Déconnez-pas les mecs!* mais ça... dans l'urgence... ça sort tout seul... une locution figée sans doute! :-)</sup>

<sup>2 : J'ai eu l'autorisation de dire ça sur *Cosette*</sup>

---

<sup>NDaCOSwt : Un commentaire de @LaurentS évoque une perception différente.

Je crois que cela dépend beaucoup du contexte évidemment. Dans le contexte de l'OP l'impératif vient d'une autorité ou d'une personne faisant autorité. Je le crois difficile de ne pas être compris autrement que directif.</sup>

<sup>Dans un contexte d'égal à égal, en famille, entre amis, je suis bien d'accord que cela dépendra beaucoup de l'intonation et du verbe. Il est clair que les *Sois prudent! / Ne rentre pas trop tard* de ma mère étaient plus des souhaits / prières que des ordres.
 D'ailleurs... c'est curieux (en fait pas vraiment) mais dans les tournures ci-dessus... les conjugaisons de l'impératif et du subjonctif (de politesse) se confondent.</sup>

<sup>Le problème est que quand l'impératif perd cette connotation directive dans la mesure où le locuteur n'a évidemment pas les moyens de me faire obtempérer, je le tiens pour l'expression du dernier fauculisme :</sup>

<sup>*Ne le prends pas mal Laurent S. mais blahblah* avec un blahblah très critique que je sais pertinemment que tu vas prendre mal... (sinon je n'aurais pas pris cette précaution oratoire) qu'est-ce que cela veut dire si ce n'est que je crains les coups de bâton en retour ? Que je dis ça... sans le dire, en tout cas... sans vraiment l'assumer ?</sup>

<sup>Le summum en la matière (de fauculisme) étant le fait de nos amis anglo-saxons et leur sempiternel impératif "*Don't take it personally*" après avoir exprimé leur mépris pour un cas général dans lequel tu ne peux pas manquer t'être reconnu.</sup>

<sup>Je pourrais aussi me souvenir de ce pauvre policier qui, pourtant conscient que ma bagnolle était en panne mais, parce qu'elle bloquait la circulation, m'avait, l'air mauvais, lancé son "Circulez!"</sup>

Comment: @Laure I am wondering why this question didn't get much attention. Is it something obvious? I don't think so. At least with answers there is no consensus.

Comment: Thanks for this GREAT answer. For answers like this, FSE is better than any grammar book:-)! I guess my colleagues are right.

Comment: @Laure : Pardon! En fait il se trouve tout en bas de la contrib. Car j'ai rarement l'idée de faire une note dans le fil de l'écriture de la contrib. L'idée me vient après et... dans le désordre. Après... quand j'ai écrit la note 1 et que j'en ai besoin d'une autre, je mets la 2, où qu'elle se situe car j'ai la flemme de corriger tout le bastringue. Je remets dans l'ordre ASAP.

Comment: @Dimitris : Oui! Ils ont raison étant donné ce fameux *nous de majesté* que j'évoque en bas de contribution et que les plus fameux des profs des siècles <= XIX usaient. De beaucoup moins fameux en abusaient vers mi XXe du haut de leur estrade... ça passait... beaucoup moins bien...

Comment: Très belle réponse, tant sur le fond que sur la forme. Je ne partage pas ton avis sur le côté impoli ou directif, mais c'est le principe d'un avis :-)

Comment: @aCOSwt Une remarque essentielle sur l'impératif « disons » !

Comment: @LaurentS. Merci. Oui! Le côté impoli ou directif dépendra effectivement beaucoup du contexte. J'ai ajouté une petite note sur le sujet.

Comment: @LPH : Admettons!

Answer (score 3):

« Imaginons » is hardly used in mathematics and the physical sciences. « Considérons » is used to state a problem or a question that is important enough or to state possibilities within those. « Supposons » is another term used in that domain but it is more pragmatic, it is applied more often to the formulation of hypotheses within a problem. « Disons » is used only for formulationg evaluations of no major interest in the reasoning.

- Prenons un rectangle, disons qu'il a pour dimensions 10x6.

- Prenons un triangle ABC, **disons** que c'est un triangle quelconque.
- Prenons un autre triangle, DEF, **supposons** qu'il est isocèle, avec DE=FE.

No, these forms do not sound pompous in colloquial speech as long as they are used as part of a reasoning and « imaginons » is used as well as the other terms. Some of them can be used  outside of this context.

- Faisons une partie de cartes, on verra après !
- Supposons qu'il ne vienne pas, qu'est-ce qu'on fait ?
- Disons que ce n'est pas assez important, ce n'est pas qu'ils ne le voient pas.

However outside the context of reasoning that is formal enough, in the place of « considérons » other forms will often be used as something of an indefinite nature seems to makes the term stultifying ; it could be said that it is somewhat too formal but maybe rather that it lacks in specificity.

- Considérons que la lettre n'a pas été remise. *On dira plutôt ceci :*

  - « Faisons comme si la lettre n'a pas été remise. », « Prétendons que la lettre n'a pas été remise. ».
- Imaginons qu'il n'ait pas tué sa famille, qu'est-ce que l'on en déduit immédiatement ?

Yes, of course there is a one-to-one correspondence, except for the verb in the case of « faisons » (hypothèse).

Let's take the following hypothesis  <=> Faisons l'hypothèse suivante

Comment: Thank you for this answer. You always give exhaustive replies. I like here that you did not include any ngrams and TLFi sources:-)! You have just based your answer on your experience. Nevertheless  your point of view is completely different from @aCOSwt (and of my colleagues:-)!).

Comment: I did upvote both this answer and aCOSwt's as they were both well researched. That said I agree with LPH and don't find the imperative "too imperative" in this specific case. I consider it more of an invitation than an order, especially as the speaker is included in it. "Dégageons d'ici !" for example is (to my hears at least) much less harsh than "Dégagez d'ici !"...